# Why do I get a “Property pythonPath is not allowed” on my launch.json?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, virtualenv, vscode-debugger

In my launch.json, although the property `pythonPath` works fine, the Intellisense marks it as "Property pythonPath is not allowed".

[image]

Answer (score 5):

The [debugging configuration for Python](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_set-configuration-options) does not have a `"pythonPath"` setting, so that message is actually correct. When you say that it "*works fine*", what actually happens is that it's simply *ignored* by the debugger. That's why it's only shown in a yellow squiggly line, because it's just a warning for an unused/ignored setting, and it will not stop/block the debugger.

The correct setting is simply [`"python"`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_python):

> `python`
>
> Full path that points to the Python interpreter to be used for
> debugging.
>
> If not specified, this setting defaults to the interpreter identified
> in the `python.pythonPath` setting, which is equivalent to using the
> value `${config:python.pythonPath}`. To use a different interpreter,
> specify its path instead in the `python` property of a debug
> configuration.
>
> Alternately, you can use a custom environment variable that's defined
> on each platform to contain the full path to the Python interpreter to
> use, so that no additional folder paths are needed.
>
> If you need to pass arguments to the Python interpreter, you can use
> the syntax `"python": ["<path>", "<arg>",...]`.

Maybe it defaulted to a valid `"python.pythonPath"` setting on your environment, which made it look like that it's working.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I already tried the "python" parameter setting before trying to use the "pythonPath" parameter that shouldn't work. But with the "python" parameter set or without, it doesn't change anything and still use the default python interpreter. With the "pythonPath" that shouldn't work, it works fine. Probably a mess in my system configuration, I'll try to figure it out.

Comment: Thanks. The solution works for VS code 1.54.3, you only need: `"python": "full path to python venv here..."` option